Understanding the ‘cannot interpret ‘20’ as a data type’ error in np.dtype(20)
I’ve coded in python before for my university course but never really understood it- I’m trying to do that now.
I’m trying to understand why the following code gives an error:
import numpy as np
np.dtype(20)

Which gives the error “Cannot interpret ‘20’ as a data type”.
I am confused by this because data types include integers and floats. What I was expecting was for this to tell me whether when I type ‘20’, is this being read as an integer or a float?
There is a question posted here which has a similar title but it’s in the context of an error obtained by creating neural networks and honestly none of the answers really explain anything. The closest one gets to an explanation is ‘the second parameter should be a data type and not a number’ but I don’t understand this… surely there are no such thing object types as ‘numbers’ in python and everything that looks like a ‘number’ is either an integer or a float to some precision from the perspective off the computer?
I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me understand what is happening when I type ‘20’ into python because it doesn’t seem to be what I thought.

np.dtype(int), np.dtype(float), np.dtype('int'), np.dtype('int32'), np.dtype(np.int32), ... are example of valid usage of dtype. It is because np.dtype(float) == np.float64 that I know that float is treated as a synonym of "float64"

"What I was expecting was [...]" - Why were you expecting that? Did you assume it would work like type(20)?

np.dtype(20) doesn't mean "give me the dtype of 20". It means "what do you get if you try to treat 20 as a dtype?" Trying to treat 20 as a dtype doesn't make sense, hence the error.
Note that dtypes are a NumPy-specific thing, distinct from ordinary Python types. You may have gotten things mixed up with type(20), which would give you a type object representing the type of 20.

Thank you for your answer, but could you clarify what you mean by ‘what do you get if you try to treat it as a data type’? Like, what is it doing to something in trying to treat it as a data type? Isn’t everything a data type anyway? Like, what can it do to it other than outputting the data type that it is?

@Meep: First off, no, not everything is a data type. Roughly speaking, a data type is a kind of thing. 20 is not a kind of thing. int or float are kinds of things. Trying to interpret 20 as a kind of thing doesn't make sense. 20 is an int, and int is a kind of thing, but 20 isn't a kind of thing - the "is a" relationship isn't transitive.

Second, "data type" isn't a precise term for any of the things we're dealing with here - we've got two separate "type-like" concepts in the picture. We've got Python types, like int and float, and NumPy dtypes, like int32 or float64. NumPy dtypes represent information about what kind of elements a NumPy array holds - for example, 32-bit integers, or 64-bit floats. Because NumPy arrays usually work with raw machine values instead of Python objects, NumPy can't use ordinary Python types for this.

This link on NumPy's reference notes that "np.dtype" is used to define the data type, so it's looking for the definition of the data type. In simpler terms, the number 20 is an example of an integer, but it isn't the definition of an integer, leading to an error.
Addendum: The link has an example under the subheading "Array-scalar types" that shows how np.dtype is used for 32-bit integers and 128-bit complex floating-point numbers.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Every python object has a type.  If you define a class, and make an instance, type is the class used to create it.
If I type something like '20', the interpreter parses it and makes an instance of some class.
Examples of int, float and str:
In [226]: type(20)
Out[226]: int

In [227]: type(20.0)
Out[227]: float

In [228]: type('20')
Out[228]: str

I can also use int as a function:
In [230]: int('20')
Out[230]: 20

Functions also have a type:
In [231]: type(int)
Out[231]: type

But you used dtype, which is a numpy class (and function), and property of numpy arrays.
In [232]: arr = np.array([20])

In [233]: arr
Out[233]: array([20])

In [234]: type(arr)
Out[234]: numpy.ndarray

In [235]: arr.shape, arr.dtype
Out[235]: ((1,), dtype('int32'))

The type of the array is ndarray.  It has attributes like shape and dtype.
np.dtype is also a function, which can return a dtype object.  It is well documented (in the numpy docs, not the python ones).  There are lots of string alias for something like this:
In [236]: np.dtype('int')
Out[236]: dtype('int32')

But you can't give it a number, or some general python object.  If that's confusing you need to spend sometime reading the numpy docs, and specific functions like np.dtype.
In [237]: np.dtype(20)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[237], line 1
----> 1 np.dtype(20)

TypeError: Cannot interpret '20' as a data type

That error didn't say "Cannot determine the data type of '20'".
You referenced a similar error in a previous SO:
In [238]: np.zeros(2,20)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[238], line 1
----> 1 np.zeros(2,20)

TypeError: Cannot interpret '20' as a data type

If you read the np.zeros docs, you'll see that it expects at least one argument, a shape or shape tuple.  If there's a second argument, it should be a dtype or something that can be interpreted as such:
In [239]: np.zeros((2,20), 'int')
Out[239]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

This was short for:
In [240]: np.zeros((2,5), np.dtype('int32'))
Out[240]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [241]: _.dtype
Out[241]: dtype('int32')

Hopefully that explains why you got the same error as that link.  Both of you were trying to use '20' as an argument to a np.dtype function.
You asked about integers versus numbers etc.  All types are part of a class hierarchy.  For int it's pretty short:
In [249]: type(20).__mro__
Out[249]: (int, object)

An element of the arr array looks the same:
In [250]: arr[0]
Out[250]: 20

But it's a numpy scalar, and has a longer mro:
In [251]: type(arr[0])
Out[251]: numpy.int32

In [252]: type(arr[0]).__mro__
Out[252]: 
(numpy.int32,
 numpy.signedinteger,
 numpy.integer,
 numpy.number,
 numpy.generic,
 object)

Python integers and numpy ones are similar, but there are important differences.  Hopefully the numpy docs will explain that.
